# Is it possible to embed an existing SWF into an Air for iOS app?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash

One of my customers has many SWF and he would like to port them to iPad. However, he only has the SWFs, not the FLAs.

I 'd like to know if it is a way to run the SWFs inside an Air for iOS app. I´ve read you can import then with a Loader, but they will only run as an animation ignoring all the code inside them.

Thanks, any help is welcome!

[UPDATE] I´ve read something about using SWC, but still not sure if they will run the code.

Comment: That is correct, no ActionScript in swf files is allowed, since Apple don't allow third party runtimes for executing loaded code in iOS. swf files that only contains timeline animations, and no code, can be loaded and run, but that is a rather small use case.

Comment: You can indeed use swc files, but you won't use a loader to load them.  You would include them as libraries to your main application.  Unfortunately, without the fla you might not be able to generate a swc with the code.

Comment: Packaging the swf files as swc files could be an option. swc files are not loaded at runtime, they are included at compile time. Normally, swc files are not built from existing swf files, but it should be possible, since swc files are in practice zip files with an .swc extension and specified content http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_SWC_file

Comment: Decompiling the files with Trillix or a comparable tool could be an option.  I would prefer having the sources to embedding the binaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update, Oct 2012:**

In Adobe AIR 3.5, adl is introducing a feature called "multiple SWF support" that allows the use of Loaders to load SWFs delivered in the .ipa (local files, not from servers) to have code in them. The adl compiler AOT compiles SWFs that are included in the .ipa, allowing them to be loaded and work under iOS.

AIR 3.5 is currently in beta at the time of this writing, available on the adobe labs site:

- [AIR 3.5 on Adobe labs website](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashplatformruntimes/air3-5/)
- [AIR 3.5 release notes](http://labsdownload.adobe.com/pub/labs/flashplatformruntimes/shared/air3-5_flashplayer11-5_releasenotes.pdf)

Note that this feature requires -swf-version=18 or greater of the root SWF (not necessarily the assets being loaded) and AIR namespace ending in 3.5 in the application xml file.

**Older answer:**

The reason external SWFs with code in the doesn't work is that Air's ADT compiler cross-compiles your root SWF (and only your root swf) into objective-c code consumable by an iOS device.  Both [embedded] SWFs and those included in the .ipa (prior to AIR 3.5) are not cross-compiled.

I created a workaround for this problem for embedded assets:

```
[Embed(source="gameLevel.swf")]
  private var gameLevel:Class;

 ...

 addChild(new gameLevel());
```

In this scenario, if gameLevel.swf has code in it, it typically wouldn't work in iOS, because new gameLevel() would create a Loader and interpret SWF bytecode.  But, if you first run the above SWF through my tool called SWFMerge, it will take your embedded SWF and merge it into your root SWF.  The result is that ADT will compile your embedded code into objective-C, it will work on iOS, and note: new gameLevel() now results in an instance of your asset - NOT a Loader.

The SWFMerge tool is here:

http://www.onetacoshort.com/temp/SWFMerge_alpha.swf

LMK if this workaround works for you or if you have trouble.  Cheers!

-Jeff

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can,

Apple does not allow your application to download SWF's using Loader from the internet but you ARE allowed to embed and include them inside of your .ipa

To do this you would use the embed tag

```
[Embed("myswf.swf", mimeType="application/octet-stream")] private var mySwf:Class;
```

You can then use

```
swf = new mySwf();
swf.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
```

And interact with the swf inside that complete handler

I wanted to add to this that it is possible to compile a SWF that is not able to be loaded

Comment: There is one problem, though: You can only use the library symbols this way.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915924/access-maintimeline-symbol-using-class-level-embed/8920101#8920101